# What is the appropriate response for a broken link in the request entity?

Tags: rest

Say I have a RESTful API that binds a user to a company:

`PUT http://example.com/users/john.smith`

```
{
  "company": "http://example.com/companies/Nintendo"
}
```

but the referenced company does not exist (possibly due to a race condition, possibly due to user error). The operation cannot complete successfully because the database requires foreign keys to point to existing rows. What is the appropriate response code and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would return a `HTTP 400 - Bad Request`, probably adding in the response body some hint (e.g. Nintendo is not a valid option). It's not a `404 - Not found` error, since the URL and the resources referenced in it are correct.

As a side note about the body of your request

```
{
  "company": "http://example.com/companies/Nintendo"
}
```

I would expect users to pass only a name, or an id about the company, not the whole URI. You add more complexity without possibly gaining anything. Imagine a user passing a valid company name, e.g. *Sega*, in a URI that has a typo, e.g. *comp***p***anies*. I'm guessing your backend would try to access this URI, and, failing that, it would return an error. Well, you could, but to me it seems that you are making both yours and your users life difficult.

Comment: I agree with the first part of your answer, but not the second. We are associating a user with a company, not a company name, which is why a URI is used. Remember, REST APIs are primarily for computers, not humans. For all we know, the client picked the company out of a list. As for handling company name to URI resolution (for humans) you could use a separate mechanism such as `http://example.com/companies?q=comppanies` which would return a list of possible matches.

Comment: Well, it seems like we mostly agree and the others are small details. I would still use just the name or the id, but no approach is wrong or non-RESTful (I could say that I match a user with a company, not a company URI - but that's just playing with words). And I also agree that since it will be mainly accessed by computers, not humans, then there is not much to worry (maybe you get the overhead in your backend of hitting the given URI, to extract company details, but you might be ok with that).

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely a `4xx` error, since the information provided by the client is the source of the problem.

Since we are dealing with problems of **semantic** nature, [HTTP 1.1's WebDAV `422`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#page-78) is the best suited response code:

> **`422 Unprocessable Entity (WebDAV)`**
>
> The `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` status code means the server **understands** the content type of the request entity - hence a `415 (Unsupported Media Type)` status code is inappropriate -, and the **syntax** of the request entity is **correct** - thus a `400 (Bad Request)` status code is inappropriate - but was unable to process the contained instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but **semantically erroneous**, XML instructions.

Of course, don't leave your client alone in the dark and make sure you explain in the response body **why** the error is happening.

---

Now some discussion regarding why not other codes, first the three more confusing and then the rest:

`400 Bad Request`: *The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.* - The syntax is ok (the request is well-formed). The error is semantic (company does not exist). Furthermore, the client can repeat the request **without** modification at all at some other time (after adding the company) and it may work. So, not 400.

`403 Forbidden` *The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated*: This is usually issued when the client is authenticated but lacks permission (write, read, or other requirement) to the requested resource. Not 403 as well.

`404 Not Found` *The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI*: Notice the error is about the **Request-URI**, which is the user. This response should be sent when the **user** (the one in the URI) does not exist, not the company.

And the others:

`401 Unauthorized` *The request requires user authentication*: No need to argue here.

`402 Payment Required` *This code is reserved for future use*: Neither here.

`405 Method Not Allowed`: Not about the HTTP method (`GET`, `PUT`, etc.).

`406 Not Acceptable`: This has to do with accept headers.

`407 Proxy Authentication Required`: Proxy-related.

`408 Request Timeout`: Obviously not.

`409 Conflict`: *The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource.* The current (saved before) resource (the user's company) is ok in the server. Any new company is acceptable, there can be no conflict between a new and the current company, since the new will always overwrite the current.

`410 Gone`: *The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no forwarding address is known.* Nothing to do with this either.

`411 Length Required`: It's about the `Content-Length` header.

`412 Precondition Failed`: About request-header fields.

`413 Request Entity Too Large`: Not related to the size of the entity.

`414 Request-URI Too Long`: Nor the size of the URI.

`415 Unsupported Media Type`: Entity in the request is ok (the server knows JSON).

`416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable`: About the `Range` request-header.

`417 Expectation Failed`: About the `Expect` request-header.

`423 Locked (WebDAV)` *The 423 (Locked) status code means the source or destination resource of a method is locked*: Nothing is locked here.

`424 Failed Dependency (WebDAV)` *The 424 (Failed Dependency) status code means that the method could not be performed on the resource because the requested action depended on another action and that action failed*: There is no chain of actions in the current context.

Comment: I agree and +1 for a comprehensive and logical explanation, esp. for why `400` and `404` are not appropriate for this situation

Comment: -1 because `HTTP 422` is not part of `HTTP 1.1`. It is part of the `WebDAV` extension (which is non-standard). According to http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-22#page-57 (HTTP 2.0 draft) `HTTP 400` is no longer restricted to invalid syntax. It is now allowed in response to a "nonsensical" input. I'm not sure whether it applies to this case, but it's worth reconsidering.

Comment: Fair point about the lack of WebDAV disclaimer (added that). But you are incongruent about the rest. WebDAV really isn't *the* HTTP 1.1, but it is a widely-known (if not the most) extension - and we are talking about web services here, not "human" web. `422` still is a `4xx` error. How can you defend HTTP 2.0 (a ***draft***!) and curse WebDAV? Besides, still in 2.0, the request of any nonen-existant company isn't "nonsensical" (absurd), they just happen to not exist. Nonsensical is `PUT`ting a company into, say, a user URI.

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2434-HTTP-Status-Codes-For-Invalid-Data-400-vs-422.htm: More about WebDAV status codes' adoption (also look at the discussion in the comments). **Bottom-line:** If you must stick to standard plain HTTP, use `400`, but it still does not make direct sense, which tells close-to-nothing as a status code. If you want to be extreme-specific, create your own `499` code and explain it to your clients. If you want the middle ground, 422 is your best shot.

Comment: I am mostly basing myself on [RESTful Web Services](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do) which was published in 2007. According to that book HTTP 400 corresponds to a `generic client-side error status, used when no other 4xx error code is appropriate. It’s commonly used when the client submits a representation along with a PUT or POST request, and the representation is in the right format, but it doesn’t make any sense.` That being said, I agree with you that for WebDAV adopters your answer makes more sense than `HTTP 400`. For non-WebDAV adopters, I think the jury is still out.

Comment: I got that book right here. Page 372: "*WebDAV defines five response codes besides 207, and some web servers define the nonstandard code 509 (“Bandwidth Limit Exceeded”). Though not part of HTTP, these status codes are **fairly well established**, and you can use them if
you like.*" -- Another point: I myself try to follow the HTTP standard (statelessness and all properties of the methods) and HATEOAS to the end. Don't know if surprises you, tho, but I'd be against the use of WebDAV **verbs** (methods), as I believe the starndard are pretty much enough. Status codes, otoh, are another story.

Comment: One final thing, you say "*For non-WebDAV adopters, I think the jury is still out.*" I don't feel like there can be discussion even there. The code is `400` and that's it. The RFC set is pretty small and all others have very clear reasons for not being appropriate here (we talked about them all, one by one). So it is `400`, not due to the reason given by the other answer (I don't downvote competing answers), but because the utter lack of a better code. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

If the server doesn't respond you could return a 404, if it does respond with an error I'd return that error.

404 is usually a permanent error that doesn't go away with a retry in a few seconds.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: The link you just gave says "No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent."

Comment: So in case you don't know you'd just assume it's temporary and keep polling forever? Or you'd assume it's permanent?

Comment: I guess, by the book, we can't make any assumptions. It says the server should return a `410 GONE` when it is certain that the user should never ask for that resource again. In a `404` the server can choose to say why it was refused (so the user can decide properly) or not (leaving the user to make its own mind based on guesswork)...

Comment: Okay let's not make assumptions, what do you do? Retry or not? Wouldn't either behavior fall into an assumption category?